# How to calculate Hamming weight (a.k.a. population count, i.e. number of 1 bits in an integer) for an integer type of unknown bitcount?

Tags: c, gcc

In C, how can I efficiently calculate the Hamming weight of an integer which is of a variable-width type, e.g. uint_fast8_t or uintmax_t?

- I cannot code a [shift and add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight#Efficient_implementation) algorithm, because I do not know until compile time how many bits are in the number.
- I cannot use the [__builtin_popcount()](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-g_t_005f_005fbuiltin_005fpopcount-4268) family of functions because I do not know which, if any, of 'unsigned int', 'unsigned long int', or 'unsigned long long int' the given type corresponds to.
- I cannot even write a function which has separate cases for each of the possible lengths, with the correct one being selected at compile time, because sizeof() isn't available in pre-processor conditionals.

Notes:

- I am compiling using GCC
- I would prefer a solution which uses the __builtin_popcount() functions if and when possible, so that I can take advantage of processor-level popcount operations when available.
- I am not actively targeting any unusual architectures, so a solution that assumes that all integer types are 8 * 2^n bits long where 0 <= n <= 4 is acceptable. That said, the rest of my code is all carefully agnostic to atypical character or integer sizes, so it would be nice to maintain that property.

Comment: Not an answer since you're C not C++ - but for C++ people: You could wrap `__builtin_popcount*` intrinsics in overloaded inline functions with different input parameter types, then just pass an integer in and let overload resolution decide which one to call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can I efficiently calculate the Hamming weight of an integer which is of a variable-width type, e.g. uint_fast8_t or uintmax_t?
>
> [...]
>
> I am compiling using GCC
>
> I would prefer a solution which uses the __builtin_popcount() functions

You can write an `if / else` statement based on the `sizeof()` the type in question:

```
int weight(uintmax_t x) {
    if (sizeof x <= sizeof int) {
        return __builtin_popcount(x);
    else if (sizeof x <= sizeof long) {
        return __builtin_popcountl(x);
    else {
        return __builtin_popcountll(x);
    }
}
```

There's a good chance that GCC recognizes that the relational expressions are compile-time constants, and therefore optimizes all of that to just calling the appropriate builtin.

Alternatively, you can just use `__builtin_popcountll(x)`; as far as I am aware, GCC provides no integer types wider than `long long int`, so that will produce the right answer in all cases.

Or you can determine which alternative to select during machine-specific build configuration (e.g. via an Autoconf or CMake test), and define a symbol that instructs GCC which of the available variants to choose.  This variation also allows you to provide a fallback in case you unexpectedly do run into an integer type wider than `long long int`.

Any of these (other than the fallback) enable you to compute the Hamming weight with a single call to a suitable builtin.  I presume that serves your apparent interest in efficient performance better than does an alternative that requires multiple calls.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the types in question are *unsigned*:

Take the number in question, grab the lower 8 bits, cast to `uint8_t`, and pass to `__builtin_popcount()`.  Shift right 8 bits and repeat until you get 0.

```
int count_bits(some_type x)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (x > 0) {
        count += __builtin_popcount((uint8_t)(x & 0xFF));
        x >>= 8;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: \__builtin_popcount() takes an unsigned int and unsigned int is guaranteed by the standard to be at least 16 bits, so it would be better to take 16 bits at a time rather than 8.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to know how many bits are in the number. You only need to know when there are none set. For an unsigned type that is easy - it will be zero.

```
int count = 0;
utype number = /* some number */;
while(number != 0) {
    if ((number & (utype)1) != 0) {
        count++;
    }
    number >>= 1;
}
```

Comment: I specified '*efficiently* calculate'; this is O(n) time, whereas an appropriate shift-and-add algorithm takes O(log(n)) *and* has no conditional looping or branching to screw up your instruction pipelining.

Comment: Well you should have been more specific instead of reeling off a list of apparent impossibilities. So sorry to have bothered you an answer that only satisfies "I do not know how many bits". I see your comment to the best reply is just as negative.

Comment: I _was_ 'more specific': 'efficient' is right there in the first sentence.

I said I do not know how many bits _when writing the code_. I - or rather the compiler - _does_ know _at compile time_ how many bits it is. That was the whole point of my question: how do I calculate it using the most efficient algorithm for the actual size determined at compile time.

As for my other comment, there is nothing negative about pointing out a bug in their code. That solution is _also_ O(n), but in that case the N tops at at 8 instead of 128 like yours, which makes it reasonable, if not optimal.